# Turn off double spacing

Tags: spacing

I want a specific section of the document to double space.
So I do

```
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \doublespacing
```

But this is applied on the entire document. How can I turnoff double spacing and resume default spacing?

Comment: `\singlespacing`

Comment: If the default for your document is single spacing, it's easier to load `setspace` without changing the global default and put `\begin{spacing}{⟨desired factor of spacing⟩} ... \end{spacing}` around the section you want differently spaced.

Comment: Thank you so much